# Join in LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In SQL I to get the distinct statement, I used `join` to get it as below

```
select distinct 
    col1 
from 
    table1 a 
inner join 
    table2 b on a.code = b.vcode
```

How can the same be implemented in LINQ over Entity Framework?

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var result = (from a in table1
              join b in table2 on a.code equals b.vcode
              select a.col1).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 45):

You can also use method syntax:

```
var query = table1.Join(table2,
                        a => a.code,
                        b => b.vcode,
                        (a,b) => a.col1)
                   .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thank you for one more solution

Comment: This is much better